How is ようで used in a sentence like this? Is it like ように?
"冷たい水の中、無いはずの体温が伝わってくるようで、私の心のどこかが柔らかくなっていく"
I don't understand this sentence. The character is not into the water so I think he's speaking metaphorically? Is it like ように here?

ように is adverbial ("do something like X"), ようだ is predicative ("it is like X"), and ようで is the continuative version of ようだ ("it is like X, and (so) ...").

Does ようで always mean "it is like X, and (so) ..."? https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/26276029.html
Seems confusing to differentiate

@whatyouexpect regarding the example there, whether something is かんたん isn't an objective fact, so it's about the initial perception. Using ようで contrastively (making the maki sushi was difficult despite appearances) doesn't seem any more strange to me than using e.g. ので contrastively.

I believe you are familiar with ～ようだ. ～ようで is nothing but a conjunctive version of ～ようだ.
